# External Hard Drives become unusable after resume from suspend

Tags: usb, hard-drive, suspend, ssd

I have an ASUS ROG STRIX B550-I GAMING, using Ubuntu 21.10, kernel 5.13.0-27-generic.

I've got two different external USB drives, one is a 2tb sandisk extreme portable, and the other is a LaCie Rugged Raid Pro 4tb.

Both of them become unusable after a resume from suspend. They'll work for a moment, and then they will get input/output errors. dmesg will show "aborted ext-4 journal detected".

Both drives at this point become unusable until a reboot. I cannot unplug and replug them back in, it doesn't seem to work.

It doesn't seem to matter if I use `s2idle` or `deep`. I've got an updated BIOS.

Anyone know what is wrong here?

edit: adding output of `fdisk -l`. I will also note that it doesn't seem to matter what filesystem I use. I've tried luks with ext4/NTFS, I've tried VeraCrypt with ext4/NTFS, and ZFS on both devices.

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 225A9A01-107A-464D-8985-F4DAA59347E8

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624   2549759   1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 2549760 976771071 974221312 464.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000365371904 bytes, 3906963617 sectors
Disk model: Extreme 55AE    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0C94FFA7-7AF4-724E-830E-4378A6216292

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 3906947071 3906945024  1.8T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sda9  3906947072 3906963455      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: 464.53 GiB, 498784534528 bytes, 974188544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: 463.57 GiB, 497754832896 bytes, 972177408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: 980 MiB, 1027604480 bytes, 2007040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdg: 3.64 TiB, 4000795591168 bytes, 7814053889 sectors
Disk model: Rugged RAID Pro 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 76CCCDF0-EF86-044C-9E35-0DD441030AC1

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdg1        2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.6T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdg9  7814035456 7814051839      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1
```

And the output of `lsusb` and `lsusb -t`:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 05e3:0748 Genesys Logic, Inc. All-in-One Cardreader
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0781:55ae SanDisk Corp. Extreme 55AE
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0451:8440 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 3297:1969 ZSA Moonlander Mark I
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0451:82ff Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05a3:9331 ARC International Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0451:8442 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 059f:10b4 LaCie, Ltd Rugged RAID Pro
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 059f:0082 LaCie, Ltd RaidConfig
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 059f:10a7 LaCie, Ltd Rugged RAID Pro
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 059f:10ac LaCie, Ltd Pegasus
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1e71:2006 NZXT Smart Device V2
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1e71:2007 NZXT NZXT USB Device
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 10000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

Comment: I assume that these drives used to work, yes? Do the external drives have their own external AC power supplies? Are you using a powered USB hub? Are these USB3 drives connected to a USB3 port? Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l`. Use **Software Updater** to update to the newer -28 kernel that was released today. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I don't know if they've ever worked, they are both brand new. This seems to be related to my motherboard/chipset, it doesn't happen on my laptop (Thinkpad x250). I believe they are USB3 through USB C ports directly on the motherboard, so I am not using an external hub at all. I will update the kernel and report back.

Comment: Since these are new/empty drives, start `gparted` and lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this WILL wipe the drives), then create a standard EXT4 partition. See if the drives work then.

Comment: @heynnema They do not, I tried that first (first thing I did was wipe out the partition table they came with). It doesn't seem to matter if I use encryption or not, volume managers or not, or which filesystem. I did use cfdisk, though, just as a point of data, probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Try with `gparted`. It probably won't make a difference, but let's eliminate a cfdisk problem. You never said if the drive enclosures have their own AC power supply. Also, show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`. And in your `lsusb` I can see which one is the SanDisk, but which one is the Lacie... I see that one 4 times? Any difference if you plug these into a USB3 port, instead of a USB-C port?

Comment: Many HDD need more power than USB ports can offer. Some newer systems have newer USB ports that do offer more power.

Comment: Tried gparted, in a USB 3 spot, raw ext4 FS (no encryption, etc), no luck. `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` shows no results. The 4tb lacie drive has it's own power supply (which I am using), the smaller one is an SSD and has no external supply port. I am not sure why it shows up 4 times, though it does have 2 drives in it configured in a RAID 0 (hardware). I have also tried UAS quirks (like here: https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/SAT-with-UAS-Linux) with no luck. Weird that it works on my Thinkpad without issue

Comment: @heynnema forgot to tag you. When I say "it shows up 4 times", I mean the LaCie.

Comment: Yes, USB3 UAS is where I was heading. Last try... are there any USB or USB3 settings in your BIOS that could have an effect here? Is your CPU or RAM overclocked? You said your BIOS is current, yes?

Comment: @heynnema I did poke around in the BIOS but I didn't see anything that seemed relevant (doesn't mean it isn't there, I just don't totally know what I'm looking for). 

CPU and RAM are not overclocked.

Comment: Check for USB power-related settings. Otherwise I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema well thank you much for the help. I'll keep poking around, will post an answer here if I get it figured out.